# Как обращатся к кнопкам из класса Lang класса TranslateText, когда весь UI создан через дизайнер PyQT5 и импортируется

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, google-translate

У меня есть файл `main.py` и в нем класс `TranslateText` и есть файл с `ui.py` созданный в `Qt дизайнере`, а также есть класс `Lang` в файле `main.py`.

Моя задача чтоб при нажатии той или иной из трех кнопок выбора языка, она графически отображалась нажатой до той поры пока я не нажму другую, и соответственно она перейдет в исходный графический вид (не нажатое состояние), а другая зажмется (подобно тому как в web интерфейсе google translate).

Исходный файл main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from googletrans import Translator



class Lang():
    def __init__(self):
        self.selected_language = ''

    def set_lang(self, selected_language):
        self.selected_language = selected_language
        
        if self.ui.btn_en_lang.isChecked():
            self.ui.btn_en_lang.setDown(True)

        elif self.ui.btn_ru_lang.isChecked():
            self.ui.btn_ru_lang.setDown(True)
            
        elif self.ui.btn_de_lang.isChecked():
            self.ui.btn_de_lang.setDown(True)
    


class TranslateText(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TranslateText, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.init_UI()
    
    def init_UI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Translator') 
        self.ui.btn_translate.clicked.connect(self.translate)
        self.ui.btn_check_lang.setDown(True)
        
        self.ui.btn_en_lang.setCheckable(True)
        self.ui.btn_ru_lang.setCheckable(True)
        self.ui.btn_de_lang.setCheckable(True)

        self.ui.btn_en_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: lang.set_lang('en'))
        self.ui.btn_ru_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: lang.set_lang('ru'))
        self.ui.btn_de_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: lang.set_lang('de'))

    def translate(self):
        input_text = self.ui.input_text.toPlainText()
        translated_text = translator.translate(input_text, dest=f'{lang.selected_language}')        
        self.ui.output_text.setPlainText(translated_text.text)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lang = Lang()
    translator = Translator()      
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = TranslateText()
    application.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

ui.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(961, 521)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e0e0e0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_text = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 61, 480, 400))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.input_text.setFont(font)
        self.input_text.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 0;\n"
"padding: 25px\n"
"")
        self.input_text.setObjectName("input_text")
        self.output_text = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(481, 61, 480, 400))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.output_text.setFont(font)
        self.output_text.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 0;\n"
"padding: 25px\n"
"")
        self.output_text.setObjectName("output_text")
        self.toolbar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolbar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 961, 60))
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.toolbar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.toolbar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.toolbar.setObjectName("toolbar")
        self.btn_check_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_check_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_check_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_check_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_check_lang.setObjectName("btn_check_lang")

        self.btn_en_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_en_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(481, 0, 180, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_en_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_en_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_en_lang.setObjectName("btn_en_lang")

        self.btn_ru_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(661, 0, 140, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_ru_lang.setObjectName("btn_ru_lang")

        self.btn_de_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_de_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(801, 0, 160, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_de_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_de_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_de_lang.setObjectName("btn_de_lang")
        
        self.btn_translate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_translate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 461, 961, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_translate.setFont(font)
        self.btn_translate.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #76a4f5;\n"
"    border: 0\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border-top: 2px solid #4284f3;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_translate.setObjectName("btn_translate")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_check_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ ЯЗЫК"))
        self.btn_en_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "АНГЛИЙСКИЙ"))
        self.btn_ru_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "РУССКИЙ"))
        self.btn_de_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕМЕЦКИЙ"))
        self.btn_translate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПЕРЕВЕСТИ"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль `ui.py`

Comment: а чем он поможет, это просто конвертация ui.ui через pyuic5 в ui.py

Comment: как по мне, мне нужен ответ на вопрос как обращатся к кнопкам btn_en_lang, btn_ru_lang, btn_de_lang c класса Lang

Comment: если вам действительно нужна помощь,  опубликуйте модуль `ui.py`

Comment: Добавил код ui.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from googletrans import Translator

#from ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(961, 521)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e0e0e0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_text = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 61, 480, 400))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.input_text.setFont(font)
        self.input_text.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 0;\n"
"padding: 25px\n"
"")
        self.input_text.setObjectName("input_text")
        self.output_text = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(481, 61, 480, 400))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.output_text.setFont(font)
        self.output_text.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 0;\n"
"padding: 25px\n"
"")
        self.output_text.setObjectName("output_text")
        self.toolbar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolbar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 961, 60))
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.toolbar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.toolbar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.toolbar.setObjectName("toolbar")
        self.btn_check_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_check_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_check_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_check_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_check_lang.setObjectName("btn_check_lang")

        self.btn_en_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_en_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(481, 0, 180, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_en_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_en_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:checked {\n"                          
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")    #  Обратите внимание на замену `pressed`  на   `checked`     <<<======<

        self.btn_en_lang.setObjectName("btn_en_lang")

        self.btn_ru_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(661, 0, 140, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_ru_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:checked {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")    #  Обратите внимание на замену `pressed`  на   `checked`     <<<======<
        self.btn_ru_lang.setObjectName("btn_ru_lang")

        self.btn_de_lang = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.toolbar)
        self.btn_de_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(801, 0, 160, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_de_lang.setFont(font)
        self.btn_de_lang.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #d4e8fa;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:checked {\n"
"    border-top: 4px solid transparent;\n"
"    border-bottom: 4px solid #4284f3;\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}")    #  Обратите внимание на замену `pressed`  на   `checked`     <<<======<
        self.btn_de_lang.setObjectName("btn_de_lang")
        
        self.btn_translate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_translate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 461, 961, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_translate.setFont(font)
        self.btn_translate.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border: 0\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #76a4f5;\n"
"    border: 0\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"    color: #4284f3;\n"
"    border-top: 2px solid #4284f3;\n"
"}")
        self.btn_translate.setObjectName("btn_translate")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_check_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ ЯЗЫК"))
        self.btn_en_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "АНГЛИЙСКИЙ"))
        self.btn_ru_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "РУССКИЙ"))
        self.btn_de_lang.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕМЕЦКИЙ"))
        self.btn_translate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПЕРЕВЕСТИ"))


class Lang(QtWidgets.QWidget):                                       # QtWidgets.QWidget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                 # +++
        super(Lang, self).__init__(parent)                           # +++
        
        self.parent = parent                                         # +++
        
        self.selected_language = ''

    def set_lang(self, selected_language):
        self.selected_language = selected_language

# -       if self.ui.btn_en_lang.isChecked():
# -           self.ui.btn_en_lang.setDown(True)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.isChecked() and selected_language == 'en':
            self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.setDown(True)
            if self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.setChecked(False)
            if self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.setChecked(False)

        if self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.isChecked() and selected_language == 'ru':
            self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.setDown(True)
            if self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.setChecked(False) 
            if self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.setChecked(False) 
            
        if self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.isChecked() and selected_language == 'de':
            self.parent.ui.btn_de_lang.setDown(True)
            if self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_en_lang.setChecked(False) 
            if self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.isChecked(): self.parent.ui.btn_ru_lang.setChecked(False)             
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    

class TranslateText(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TranslateText, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lang = Lang(self)                                         # +++ !!!
        
        self.init_UI()
    
    def init_UI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Translator') 
        self.ui.btn_translate.clicked.connect(self.translate)
        self.ui.btn_check_lang.setDown(True)
        
        self.ui.btn_en_lang.setCheckable(True)
        self.ui.btn_ru_lang.setCheckable(True)
        self.ui.btn_de_lang.setCheckable(True)

        self.ui.btn_en_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: self.lang.set_lang('en'))  
        self.ui.btn_ru_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: self.lang.set_lang('ru'))
        self.ui.btn_de_lang.clicked.connect(lambda: self.lang.set_lang('de'))

    def translate(self):
        input_text = self.ui.input_text.toPlainText()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        if input_text and self.lang.selected_language:
            translated_text = translator.translate(input_text, dest=f'{self.lang.selected_language}')        
            self.ui.output_text.setPlainText(translated_text.text)    
        else: 
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 
                    'ВНИМАНИЕ', 
                    'Введите текст для перевода \nи выберите язык, \nна который будем переводить!')        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
#    lang = Lang()                                                   # ---
    translator = Translator()      
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = TranslateText()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
то есть Вы собрали 2 файла (дизайн + логику) в один файл? так?

Comment: И еще один вопрос, я так-то самоучка, задумка бла разделить UI и логику в разные файлы... так возможно в данном случаи? или это не логично\эффективно\не целесообразно...?)

Comment: @ДенисБудяк то, что вы пишите совсем не принципиально, делайте как вам удобно. В `main.py` делаете импорт `from ui import Ui_MainWindow` и все. Обратите внимание, что я внес изменения в модуль `ui.py`. Основное, что  сделал: создал экземпляр класса `Lang` в классе `TranslateText`, обратите внимание на `parent` и измененный метод `set_lang`. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour